# C# method for encoding numbers such as 12 to obfuscated strings such as JH21EW3C or whatever

Tags: asp.net

Instead of having parameters such as  i want to have .

This is because I don't want to offer a simple way to see all content just by replacing 12 with 13, 14, 15 etc.

So I need a method which can encode a number into a string, and than decode.

something like

```
httP://mysite.com?image=+encode(myNumber);when I create the link and
```

decode(imageParam); when I get the value from the HTTp request.

Is there any method available which already does this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1:

Don't use numbers to begin with. Use a [GUID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.aspx).

Option 2:

Hash your numbers. MD5 is a fast hash algorithm (though rather weak and the original value easily discoverable these days). You may want to use SHA1 or SHA2 instead.

Option 3:

Encrypt your numbers so you can decrypt them back later. This would normally be computationally very intensive.

---

I would personally go with option 1 and not use integers at all.

Comment: Aren't they the same option? If hashes are used, there's no point in keeping the numbers around anymore, since the hash for each number would need to be remembered, making the number itself redundant. :)

Comment: so u sugest adding a new field in my table with a type of guid?

Comment: @Ryan - I can't really suggest anything about the database, since this is the first you have mentioned one. Perhaps clarify in your question the context of what you are doing?